# Heroku ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, git, heroku

I'm getting this error when I try `git push Heroku master` and when I click to the link I get this message

> "Method Not Allowed"

> Heroku ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: No such file or directory

What can I do to fix this?

The Error start from this line:

[image]

Requirements file:

[image: requirement txt]

Comment: You seem to use a virtual environment, remove all the `@...` in your `requirements.txt`, also comment or edit you post with the virtual environment manager you use

Comment: I had try removing all the line starting @ it seems that is still reading the directory, as the error prompted remain unchanged. The environment I'm using is version 3.7

Comment: Don't post images of code or error stack traces. Please edit the post to include that information as text. Consider [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out really appreciate as it is my first time posting in stackoverflow